# Can tokens created by planeswalkers do commander damage

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-commander-damage

I was playing a game with someone and they said they do because planeswalkers can't attack, so the tokens created by them count as commander creatures. Is that true? I can't find any rules that talk about this.

Comment: I assume that the planeswalker in question was a commander? Otherwise I'm not sure I see the logic.

Comment: If your planeswalker commander had an ability like Gideon's and could turn into a creature or if you use something like Mycosynth Lattice and March of the Machines, then your planeswalker can kill someone with commander damage.

Answer (score 12):

[Rule 903.3](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Commander_(format)) says

> Each deck has a legendary creature card designated as its commander. This designation is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card itself. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.

Only the **cards** that start the game as commanders count as commanders and can deal commander damage.

Comment: Well, technically any card that started as a commander can deal commander damage. :)

Comment: Apply my statement over all players and it's the same thing.

Comment: @murgatorid99 - but you can gain control of someone else's commander and deal commander damage with it. As written, your sentence may be interpreted to mean that only your commander can deal commander damage (on your behalf).

Comment: OK, I changed it. Is that better?

Answer (score 6):

No, the token does not count. Being a commander is a property of the card itself, and is non-transferable.